# RegEx to get URLs from body string

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

So I was just wondering what my `getURLs` function's issue might be. I'm trying to get all urls from within the containing body's string.

My crawler isn't crawling anything because my input urls are invalid.

```
# Get all URLs contained within the body string
def getURLs(body):
    urls = []
    tempArr = body.split("a href=")
    index = 1
    for part in tempArr:
        if part[0] == '"':
            while (part[index] != '"' and index < len(part)):
                index += 1
            if index < len(part):
                urls.append(part[1:index-1])

            index = 1
    return urls


# Open file which contains input urls
with open("test_urls.txt","rU") as infile:
    urls = [row.strip("\n") for row in infile]

class BackpageSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'backpage'
    allowed_domains = ['backpage.com']
    start_urls = urls

    def parse(self,response):
        #print response.url

        if response.status < 600:

            # all_links = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'cat')]/a/@href").extract()
            #all the links FOR THE ESCORTS on whatever page we're on
            todays_links = []
            #all  the links for today's date

            backpage_date = backpage_date_today()
            yesterday_date = backpage_date_yesterday()

            if backpage_date in response.body:
                todays_section = response.body.split(backpage_date)[1].split(yesterday_date)[0].decode('utf-8') 
                # todays_links = todays_section.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'cat')]/a/@href").extract
                todays_links = getURLs(todays_section)

                # for url in todays_links: 
                #   todays_links.append(url)
                # for url in all_links: 
                #   if url in todays_section:
                #       todays_links.append(url)

            for url in todays_links: 
                yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_ad_into_content)####HERE

            for url in set(response.xpath('//a[@class="pagination next"]/@href').extract()):
                yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)

        else:
            time.sleep(600)
            yield scrapy.Request(response.url,callback=self.parse)


    def parse_ad_into_content(self,response):
        #ipdb.set_trace()
        item = items.BackpageScrapeItem(
            url=response.url,
            backpage_id=response.url.split('.')[0].split('/')[2].encode('utf-8'),
            text = response.body,
            posting_body= response.xpath("//div[@class='postingBody']").extract()[0].encode('utf-8'),
            date = datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(hours=5),
            posted_date = response.xpath("//div[@class='adInfo']/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf-8'),
            posted_age = response.xpath("//p[@class='metaInfoDisplay']/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf-8'),
            posted_title = response.xpath("//div[@id='postingTitle']//h1/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
            )
        return item
```

The web page is: http://grandisland.backpage.com/FemaleEscorts/?layout=date

Comment: The `href` attribute isn't necessarily the first thing after the `a` in an anchor tag. Change your `.split` call to `body.split("href=")`. That will improve things, but you may still get some bogus results. BTW, there are better ways to parse HTML.

Comment: What are the better ways? I'm using xpaths but I only want to scrape a small portion of the entire page's body, rather than all of the pages. Because of this, I split the body into sections and then pulled the section I need. With this section, I call my function to find all URLs. I'm not sure how I can call an xpath on this small section. The sections are split by divs (class=date) and I only want the HTML between these two divs. There are multiple divs with class = cat that contain the URLs I need. They are of the same level as the 'date' divs.

Comment: Sorry, I was just talking about your `getURLs` function. It's ok, but it's a bit slow because it examines chars one by one. There are string `find` and `index` methods that are faster. You _could_ use regex functions from the `re` module to find the URLs, although it's generally considered a bad idea to parse HTML with regex. A lot of people like to use Beautiful Soup to parse HTML; those who want more power go for lxml, but that has a big learning curve.

Comment: Hmm, gotcha. I tried switching to href (removing the a) but it still isn't working. It's scraping through but it seems that it's not adding any valid URLs for the scraper to jump into.

Comment: usually when trying to get all urls i use this little snippet : `hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)` then `urls = hxs.select('//a/@href').extract()`